# Check list of strings for duplicates of substrings

Tags: python

I am trying to check file for duplicates in lines, but the thing is that lines might be not absolutely the same.

so the example of line is `'login:passsword:mail:mail_pass:some_data'`

and somehow I manage to get to file lines that have differnt `some_data` and same account info.

current solution:

```
tw=[]
with open('path/file.txt','r') as acp:
    acp=acp.readlines()


for h in acp:
    notd=True
    for jh in tw[::-1]:
        if ":".join(h.split(':')[0:2]) in jh:
            notd=False
            break

    if notd:
        tw.append(h)


with open('path/file.txt','w') as acpw:
    acpw.writelines(tw)
```

it checks for `login:password` duplicates and takes SO much time for file with big amount of line like 10k.

So I wonder if there is the *correct* way to make it that takes less time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `set` to hold the account infos. Loop over the rows from the file and check whether the account info has already been seen.

```
accounts = set()
tw = []

with open('path/file.txt','r') as acp:
    lines = acp.readlines()

for line in lines:
    account = tuple(line.split(':')[0:2])
    if account not in accounts:
        accounts.add(account)
        tw.append(line)

with open('path/file.txt','w') as acpw:
    acpw.writelines(tw)
```